flutter_rust_bridge does not generate correct output code
I am trying to use flutter_rust_bridge for (de)serialization from a backend API, since deserialization in flutter is a nightmare even with other libraries. However, running flutter_rust_brigde_codegen generate does not generate explicit code. I am using templates in struct.
The signature of my rust code function is:
pub async fn get_subscriber(id: &String) -> Result<ResponseEnvelope<Vec<Subscriber>>, String>

But the generated flutter code is
Future<ResponseEnvelope> getSubscriber({required String id}) =>
    RustLib.instance.api.crateApiSubscriberGetSubscriber(id: id);

How can I get it to generate the exact return type "ResponseEnvelope<List<Subscriber>>"?
